# Trying to parse this sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand what this SQL (from a MySQL installation) actually does:

```
IF(coalesce(a.entity_id, 0) != 0, 0, 1)
```

While I understand what the coalesce does I don't understand how the IF statement is modifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think:

coalesce(a.entity_id, 0) - return the first not null value,

if a.entity_id is not null you get 0 as a result of if, else 1.

a.entity_id = null => coalesce = 0 => if = 1

a.entity_id is not null => coalesce = a.entity_id => if = 0

Answer (score 2):

coalesce returns the first NON-null argument. So if `a.entity_id` is null, coalesce will return 0. the containing if() then checks if the argument is not zero, and returns 0 or 1.

basically it's a convoluted way of writing `a.entity_id IS NULL`.

Comment: `a.entity_id IS NULL or a.entity_id = 0`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the **MySQL [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function**. Basically it's a ternary operator on the boolean expression supplied in argument 1. (It sounds from your question that you understood with that COALESCE is doing.)

- If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2;
- If expr1 is FALSE, it returns expr3.

> `IF()` returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1>2,2,3);
        -> 3
mysql> SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');
        -> 'yes'
mysql> SELECT IF(STRCMP('test','test1'),'no','yes');
        -> 'no'
```

It's a really funky non-readable way of not using `a.entity_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition will be met if `a.entity_id` is a value that's not `NULL` **AND** not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual entry on IF() - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this clause will evaluate to 0 if a.entity_id is not null, and 1 otherwise.